# JSON property overwriting in for loop in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm creating a function (`processElements`) that uses a JSON object as variable (`json_template`).
This function is in charge of generating an array of that JSON object (`jsonElementArray`), setting up the values according to what is received as function parameter (`fruitsArray`).

The problem is that when I'm calling the function, it's **overwriting** the parameter of the elements that make up the array. The parameter of all elements take the value of the parameter of the **last element**.

The mentioned function is the as follows:

```
def processElements(fruitsArray):
    jsonElementArray = []
    
    for fruit in fruitsArray:
        jsonElement = json_template
        jsonElement['name'] = fruit['id']
        jsonElementArray.append(jsonElement)
    
    return jsonElementArray
```

The JSON template that I use as variable in the function is as follows:

```
json_template = {
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": ""
}
```

A sample JSON with the array that the function could receive as input is as follows:

```
jsonSample = {
    "fruits": [
        {
            "id": "apple"
        },
        {
            "id": "banana"
        },
        {
            "id": "orange"
        }
    ]
}
```

The function is being used as follows:

```
def prueba(request):
    print(processElements(jsonSample["fruits"]))
```

The (not wanted) result is as follows:

```
{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'orange'}{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'orange'}{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'orange'}
```

The expected result is as follows:

```
{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'apple'}{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'banana'}{'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'orange'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that json_template is an instance, and if you say

```py
a = json_template
```

Its still the same instance. How about instead of a global variable json_template you create a function

```py
def get_json_template():
  return { "type" : "fruit", "name" : ""}
```

Or you just inline the json template like

```py
# snip
jsonElement = { "type" : "fruit", "name" : ""}
# snip
```

I think the 2nd one is more readable.

The most pythonic way would be a list comprehension however:

```py
out = [{'type' : 'fruit', 'name' : fruit['id']} for fruit in fruits]
```

TLDR use the last one

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the three different ways to solve the problem you mentioned. I'm definetely sticking with the last one.

Answer (score 1):

DownloadPizza rightly pointed out what the issue is in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65056352), I just wanted to add a few more things:

Names! Stick to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when possible. Also, referring to the objects here as JSON might be making things more complicated than necessary.

I'm not sure if that's your real `prueba` function, but having a function which does nothing but call another one and print the result is likely superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for all the advices, I'll consider them in future occasions . Didn't know about the existence of PEP8 style either.